# Can the preamble be same for all independent claims?

Tags: claims

Let's say my patent has 5 independent method claims.

Can all these claims have the same preamble?

e.g. `A method for doing X, the method comprising:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with being boring in writing claims.